# Triying to show a image on html with Flask and phyton that changes every refresh

Tags: python, html, flask

I am making a project for University where I get data from twitter and create some graphs I then display on html with Flask. The graphs are created with matplot and then I save them like .png images. Each time the user refreshes the webpage the data also updates its shelf, so the graph is generated again. My problem is that the only way of displaying the image has been through creating the static folder and this way the image isn’t updated when the local one does. I wanted to know how I could make for the Image to change when the page is refreshed.

This is my flask application

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

labels = ["Postive", "Negative", "Neutral"]
colors = ["#00ff7f", "#d80000", "#00008B"]


@app.route("/pie")
def chart():
    negative, positive, neutral = get_data("China")
    values = [positive, negative, neutral]
    pie_labels = labels
    pie_values = values
    return render_template('pie_chart.html', image="static/images/locations.png",title='Positive and Negative', max=1700, set=zip(values, labels, colors))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And this the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

    <canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var pieData = [
        {% for item, label, colors in set %}
          {
            value: {{item}},
            label: "{{label}}",
            color : "{{colors}}"
          },
        {% endfor %}
      ];
      // get bar chart canvas
      var mychart = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
      steps = 10
      max = {{ max }}
      // draw pie chart
      new Chart(document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
    </script>
    <img src="{{ image }}">
</body>
</html>
```

The thing here as I said would be how to show the image in the web page and update it every time data is updated(refresh).

Answer (score 0):

You need another route that will return dynamic images using the Flask [send_file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file) method. You then link to this route in the HTML which your existing route returns.

Example:

```
@app.route("/images/pie")
def chart_image():
    # Get data, but only make chart image
    image_object = some_thing_to_make_image_data_for_a_country()
    return flask.send_file(image_object, mimetype="image/png")

@app.route("/pie")
def chart_data():
    # Get data, but only get values
    negative, positive, neutral = get_data(country)
    values = [positive, negative, neutral]
    pie_labels = labels
    pie_values = values
    return render_template('pie_chart.html', image="images/pie",title='Positive and Negative', max=1700, set=zip(values, labels, colors))
```

This will fetch the data twice, unless you cache the data in `app` in one route, and use the cached data in the other.